# Can we use 'Region' in in typescript react code?

Tags: typescript, region, tsx

I am looking for how to use Region in .tsx code while using Visual studio code.
In editor the intelisense shows //#region and //#endregion (might be due to some extension such as
ES7 React/Redux/... or ESLint) but after placing it in code it gives errors.

Can someone know how to use that?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please specify the errors you are getting.

Answer (score 9):

you can do it.

```
// #region fields

somecode...

// #endregion
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30901278)

Comment: Workarounds are not answers (especially if you don't mention if it's a workaround, which may confuse readers as if it's an actual answer) - proper regions can expand/collapse, for example, among other features; at least in C#.

Comment: @dylanh724 this works for folding code. i confirmed this was also the case prior to your comment. as in this article from 2 years prior: https://dev.to/hurricaneinteractive/vs-code-define-a-region-1cd1